# How to show that this $\rho$ is a linear representation of $G$ of degree $2$?

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2=\{(0,0), (1,0),(0,1),(1,1) \}$ and let $\rho:G \to GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ be the group ($G$) homomorphism defined by

$\rho(0,0)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \ \rho(1,0)=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 &-1 \end{pmatrix}, \ \rho(0,1)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \ \rho(1,1)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

How to show that this $\rho$ is a linear representation of $G$ of degree $2$ ?

Comment: In order to show that it is a linear representation, you just need to show that $\rho$ is a group homomorphism. For the degree, you can check @mtheorylord's answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a homomorphism $\rho: G \to GL(V)$ we say the degree is the dimension of the vector space $V$. In your case, we have an irreducible representation from $G$ to $2\times 2$ matrices with $\dim(V) = \dim(\mathbb{C}) = 2$ and so the degree is $2$.

Comment: Did you mean $\dim(V) = \dim_{\mathbb C} (V) = \dim_{\mathbb C} (\mathbb C^2) = 2$?